# Uploadify plugin is not supporting in Mozilla firefox browser

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, flash, jquery-plugins

I am using the uploadify software  for upload files. It is working fine in IE browser.. In Mozilla, file upload is not working. In error log I am getting following error. Please anyone tell me what fix for this ..

```
  Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/Phoenix/cgi-bin/, referer: http://m5labncibmsrv006.gcsc.att.com/Phoenix/uploadify/uploadify.swf?preventswfcaching=1433233710262
```

Comment: Sounds more like a server problem, not a browser one.

Comment: But it is working in IE browser and file permission also I have given.

Comment: Anyone can tell me how to fix this issue.. Thanks in advance..